# How to change shown price of a configurable product when filtering by size

Tags: magento, product, configurable

I have a problem whereby I have set up configurable products, lets say t shirts in small, medium & large, with different prices for each size.

On my t shirt category page the price shown against each product is for the cheapest size (single).

If the user filters to show double, the price shown will still be for the single. How can I show prices for the double? (I do need to have products set up in this configuration, otherwise I would use simple products in each size)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Options which is a standard feature for Magento.

When editing the product (simple r configurable) goto the custom options tab near the bottom.

then add a new custom option and choose dropdown.

All you need to do then is mark it as a required field and input the various sizes and the increase in cost for each.